# Get current language in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How I can get current language in Laravel? I need get these codes: `ro_RO`, `en_US` e.t.c..

When I write:

```
app()->getLocale();
```

I get only: `ro`, `en`.. 
How I can get: `ro_RO`, `en_US` e.t.c?

I need set these codes for function `setLocale`:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL,app()->getLocale() . '.UTF-8');
```

My solution is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Default is set in `config/app.php` as `en` change it to

```
'locale' => 'en_US',
```

You can add multiple locales as below

```
'locales' => ['en_US' => 'English', 'ro_RO' => 'Romanian'],
```

And fire the command,

```
php artisan config:cache
```

It should work.

By using official doc, you can set locale as

```
$locale = App::getLocale();
App::setLocale($locale);
```